# How to prevent auto break line in PHP mail script

Tags: php, email, line-breaks

I wrote a PHP script, which build message from some data and send it to a mail address. But there is a problem - my message is quite wide (strings are pretty long) and I cannot shrink it.
So what I want is to prevent auto break in message, sent to mail address using PHP script. Is this possible? I want message to be in original width, and you must scrolle to see whole message.

Also, I there are some line breaks that needs to be there, so I cannot just replace all \n and \r with empty string.

Comment: Are you sending plaintext or HTML formatted mails?

Comment: @Butt4cak3 plaintext.

Comment: Then what you're trying to do is not possible. You cannot control how the mail client at the recieving end renders plaintext.

Comment: OK, so I have to HTML format the mail. Thank you.

Comment: @Butt4cak3 is it possible, to use bootstrap smarty to format mail?

Comment: I don't know what that is. Sorry.